# map key to the pipe symbol (|) in karabiner-elements

Tags: karabiner

I'm trying to bind `shift + delete` to `|` in karabiner, for my HHKB keyboard.

I indeed can map the above sequence to `backslash`, which is probably the lower case `|`, but I haven't found any way to map it directly to the `|` char.

This is what I've tried:

```
      {
        "description": "shift + delete to pipe",
        "manipulators": [
          {
            "from": {
              "key_code": "delete_or_backspace",
              "modifiers": {
                "mandatory": [
                  "shift"
                ]
              }
            },
            "to": [
              {
                "key_code": "backslash"
              }
            ],
            "type": "basic"
          }
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add

```
"modifiers": ["left_shift"]`

"to": [
  {
    "key_code": "backslash",
    "modifiers": ["left_shift"]
  }
]
```